# Drawing an SVG Raphael path gives error and doesn't accept variables

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, raphael

I'm trying to make a simple X axis for a chart using Raphael SVG path, but the variables for `M(moveto)` and `L(lineto)` aren't getting accepted.

```
var x1 = x,
    y1 = y+height,
    x2 = x+width,
    y2 = y+height;
var xAxis = SVGpaper.path("Mx1,y1 Lx2,y2").attr({stroke: "config.axisColor", "stroke-width": 1});
```

It gives the error:

Error: Problem parsing `d="M,0,0"`

Am I making some error in declaring the variables or in the syntax for path? I can't find any code to refer to, so please advice some tips!

Comment: Can you create a test example for us in Jsfiddle so that we can debug this for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just passing the string "Mx1,y1 Lx2,y2" i.e with the variable names rather than their values.

You want this...

```
SVGpaper.path("M" + x1 + "," + y1 + " L" + x2 + "," + y2).attr({stroke: "config.axisColor", "stroke-width": 1});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Was overlooking such a simple task. It worked like a charm!